# Crystal report sdk for java not working in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report viewer jar files (It supports JDK 11) for Java Swing. It is working fine in Windows but producing null pointer error in Ubuntu 18. By default Ubuntu contains openJDK 11 so uninstalled it and installed Oracle JDK also. Still the problem persists. Following is the error.

```
12:38:34.268 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter -  detected an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.opentype.tables.OS2Table.<init>(SourceFile:108)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.FontEmbeddingSession.if(SourceFile:116)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.FontEmbeddingSession.a(SourceFile:104)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.pdflib.r.if(SourceFile:594)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.pdflib.r.a(SourceFile:424)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.pdflib.PdfDocumentManager.a(SourceFile:337)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:1584)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:1492)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:780)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:729)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:683)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.if(SourceFile:633)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:1951)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:447)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.byte(SourceFile:323)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:303)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:283)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.b.a(SourceFile:217)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.PdfAdvancedDocumentModeller.a(SourceFile:177)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.page.pdf.AdobePDFExporter.a(SourceFile:252)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.page.pdf.AdobePDFExporter.processFormattedContent(SourceFile:200)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.a.a(SourceFile:105)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.a.a(SourceFile:253)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.ExportSupervisorEx.if(SourceFile:647)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.ExportSupervisorEx.a(SourceFile:597)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.a(SourceFile:641)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.int(SourceFile:677)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.do(SourceFile:1944)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.if(SourceFile:661)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:167)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.a(SourceFile:529)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.call(SourceFile:526)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ThreadGuard.syncExecute(SourceFile:102)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.for(SourceFile:525)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.int(SourceFile:424)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(SourceFile:352)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.a(SourceFile:54)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.execute(SourceFile:67)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent$a.execute(SourceFile:716)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.CommunicationChannel.a(SourceFile:125)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:537)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.dt.a(SourceFile:186)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:1558)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:337)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.if(SourceFile:224)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:148)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:129)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:112)
    at main.BillPrintUsingPDF.Print(BillPrintUsingPDF.java:46)
    at main.DotMatrixPrinting.actualPrint(DotMatrixPrinting.java:47)
    at main.PrintPreview$3.actionPerformed(PrintPreview.java:122)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at main.PrintPreview.showTextFileWithPrintOption(PrintPreview.java:157)
    at main.DotMatrixPrinting.print(DotMatrixPrinting.java:31)
    at report.DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.printToDotMatrixPrinter(DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.java:295)
    at report.DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.printingViaDOS(DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.java:182)
    at investigation.BillingOPStaffReprint.printOPBillingStaff(BillingOPStaffReprint.java:939)
    at investigation.BillingOPStaffReprint$9.mouseClicked(BillingOPStaffReprint.java:357)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6638)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException: java.lang.NullPointerException---- Error code:-2147467259 Error code name:failed
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.if(SourceFile:238)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:148)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:129)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.export(SourceFile:112)
    at main.BillPrintUsingPDF.Print(BillPrintUsingPDF.java:46)
    at main.DotMatrixPrinting.actualPrint(DotMatrixPrinting.java:47)
    at main.PrintPreview$3.actionPerformed(PrintPreview.java:122)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1031)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at main.PrintPreview.showTextFileWithPrintOption(PrintPreview.java:157)
    at main.DotMatrixPrinting.print(DotMatrixPrinting.java:31)
    at report.DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.printToDotMatrixPrinter(DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.java:295)
    at report.DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.printingViaDOS(DMPReceiptBillingOPStaff.java:182)
    at investigation.BillingOPStaffReprint.printOPBillingStaff(BillingOPStaffReprint.java:939)
    at investigation.BillingOPStaffReprint$9.mouseClicked(BillingOPStaffReprint.java:357)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6638)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.opentype.tables.OS2Table.<init>(SourceFile:108)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.FontEmbeddingSession.if(SourceFile:116)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.fontembedding.FontEmbeddingSession.a(SourceFile:104)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.pdflib.r.if(SourceFile:594)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.pdflib.r.a(SourceFile:424)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.pdflib.PdfDocumentManager.a(SourceFile:337)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:1584)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:1492)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:780)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:729)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.a(SourceFile:683)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.a.if(SourceFile:633)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:1951)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:447)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.byte(SourceFile:323)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:303)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.d.a(SourceFile:283)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.b.a(SourceFile:217)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.format.page.pdf.dom.PdfAdvancedDocumentModeller.a(SourceFile:177)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.page.pdf.AdobePDFExporter.a(SourceFile:252)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.exporters.page.pdf.AdobePDFExporter.processFormattedContent(SourceFile:200)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.a.a(SourceFile:105)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.a.a(SourceFile:253)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.ExportSupervisorEx.if(SourceFile:647)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.export2.ExportSupervisorEx.a(SourceFile:597)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.a(SourceFile:641)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.int(SourceFile:677)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.do(SourceFile:1944)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.if(SourceFile:661)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:167)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.a(SourceFile:529)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.call(SourceFile:526)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ThreadGuard.syncExecute(SourceFile:102)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.for(SourceFile:525)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.int(SourceFile:424)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(SourceFile:352)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.a(SourceFile:54)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.execute(SourceFile:67)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent$a.execute(SourceFile:716)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.CommunicationChannel.a(SourceFile:125)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:537)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.dt.a(SourceFile:186)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:1558)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:337)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.PrintOutputController.if(SourceFile:224)
    ... 85 more
```

```
{


**ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream)reportClientDoc.getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);
            reportClientDoc.close();**
            
            //ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream)reportClientDoc.getPrintOutputController().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);
            byte byteArray[] = new byte[byteArrayInputStream.available()];
            File file = new File(EXPORT_FILE);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(byteArrayInputStream.available());
            int x = byteArrayInputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArrayInputStream.available());
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, x);
            byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            byteArrayInputStream.close();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            
            PDDocument pd= PDDocument.load(file);
            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pd,Orientation.LANDSCAPE));
            PDFPageable nice=new PDFPageable(pd,Orientation.AUTO);
            
            //job.setPrintable(new PDFPrintable(pd,Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE));
            job.print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the fonts and that Crystal Report are using
MS Core fonts that is needed to be installed on a Linux system.

Have you followed the instructions at
https://reportserver.net/en/guides/admin/chapters/SAP-Crystal-Reports/ ?

Steps needed to install on a Ubuntu systems are:

> If your Linux distribution is based on Debian (this is the case with the Bitnami packages), you can run the following commands for installing the MS TrueType core fonts:

```sh
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
ln -s /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts /opt/bitnami/java/lib/fonts
```

> Depending on your Linux distribution, you may also have to check the following directory:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/jre/lib/fonts
```

> When you have successfully installed the ttf-mscorefonts package, you will be able to run Crystal reports on a Linux-based environment.